# If f is injective then $f•f^{-1}(y)=y$ for all $y\in R(f)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Below is part of the the question that i have to prove.

> f is injective then $f•f^{-1}(y)=y$ for all $y\in R(f)$ where $R(f)$ is range of $f$

**My attempt**: let $f$ be injective and $y=f(x)$ then $f^{-1}(y)=x$, so that as $f$ injective above gives, $f(f^{-1}(y))=f(x)=y$ and hence result. Am i correct?

(Is there is any detail that i left) or it is sufficient.

Comment: Looks good to me

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is correct. But in an exam I would not give you the full points. You did not even *mention* the range of $f$ in your proof although it is an essential part of the question.

Let $y\in R(f)$. Then there is a $x\in D(f)$ such that $f(x) = y$. Due to injectivity of $f$ this $x$ is unique. Thus $f^{-1}(y) = x$ and $f(f^{-1}(y)) = f(x) = y$.

Comment: Isn't, saying that "let $y=f(x)$ means $y\in R(f)$?

Comment: I think some persons would *yes* and some *no*. Maybe I am too strict.